# Get records from NOT EXISTS and IN subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, not-exists

I have a query that needs to perform the following: **Get all attendee accounts that do not have meetings scheduled during the following dates and times.**

You can run samples [here](http://chemoutsourcing.com/sample.php?_date=2016-09-20&_time=11:30,12:00). I already have a date and two times added in the URL.

In my above link results you'll see Alex Hendry listed. He has a meeting at 11:00.  Since I am getting only times at 11:30 and 12:00 his name appears. However, if I change the times to 11:00 and 11:30 his name does not appear; I understand that since 11:00 falls into the conditions he shouldn't appear.

How can I change my above query to return Alex Hendry for the 11:30 availability?

Comment: sample data would help.

Comment: @Angry Spartan The result you get does seem to match with what you stated as your requirements. The ones that have meetings at 7:00, 7:30 and 8:00 DO have meetings within the range you stated and therefore fulfill the requirements you gave (have meetings at 7:00 or 7:30) and are correctly excluded. You need to clarify exactly what you want regarding anyone who has meetings during the hours stated but also meetings at other hours.

Comment: I added an active link that you can use for sample test results.